# разделение чисел на цифры

Tags: python, массивы, числа

Нужно числа из массива `а` разделить на цифры и занести в массив `о`, но у меня вместе с цифрами в массив заносятся запятые и прочие ненужные вещи.

```
import math
a=[]
k=int(input('введи количество вводимых значений:'))
for i in range(k):
    a.append(input())
o=[]
for i in str(a):
    o.append(list(i.split()))
#x = [int(a) for a in str(num)]

print(str(o))
```

Comment: `o = list(''.join(a))`. Если нужно чтобы список `o` состоял из цифр, а не из строк с цифрами, то `o = list(map(int, ''.join(a)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Получение первого списка можно записать в одну строку с помощью спискового включения. Отмечу, что если вы перебираете что-то в цикле for, но не используйте значение, то переменную принято называть нижним подчеркиванием, хоть это и не обязательно.

Разбить числа на цифры можно двойным списковым включением тоже в одну строку. Первый цикл перебирает числа. А второй цикл перебирает цифры в этих числах, приведенных к строке и приводит их обратно к числу (если это конечно нужно по условиям задачи).

```py
a = [input() for _ in range(int(input('введи количество вводимых значений:')))]
o = [int(digit) for num in a for digit in str(num)]
print(o)
```